# How to total results within the query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT cb.customers_id, cb.products_id, p.products_model, pd.products_name, cb.customers_basket_quantity, p.products_price, (p.products_price * cb.customers_basket_quantity) AS product_total
    FROM customers_basket cb, products p, products_description pd
    WHERE cb.customers_id =194075
        AND cb.products_id = pd.products_id
        AND p.products_id = pd.products_id
```

I am trying to figure out if I can get a "cart_total" without having to do another query, or use PHP to keep a running total.

I wasn't sure if I could use the CASE statement to do something.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT cb.customers_id, cb.products_id, p.products_model, pd.products_name, cb.customers_basket_quantity, p.products_price, (p.products_price * cb.customers_basket_quantity) AS product_total,

(SELECT sum(p.products_price * cb.customers_basket_quantity) 
FROM customers_basket cb, products p
WHERE cb.customers_id =194075
AND cb.products_id = p.products_id
group by cb.customers_id) AS cart_total

FROM customers_basket cb, products p, products_description pd
WHERE cb.customers_id =194075
AND cb.products_id = pd.products_id
AND p.products_id = pd.products_id
```

A link to *[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1f391/1)*

Comment: That's not working.  The 'cart_total' column is just giving me the same number that is in 'product_total'

Comment: @Dizzy49 right! try the updated version above. I created a demo here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1f391/1  (I didn't include all the fields in the examples - only the ones which are relevant for the question)

Answer (score 0):

You can do a cart total, but you want to drop some of the columns from the `group by` and `select` (they are not appropriate at the cart level).  You should also use standard ANSI join syntax:

```
SELECT cb.customers_id, cb.customers_basket_quantity,
       sum(p.products_price * cb.customers_basket_quantity) AS product_total
FROM customers_basket cb join
     products p
     on cb.products_id = p.products_id join
     products_description pd
     on p.products_id = pd.products_id
WHERE cb.customers_id = 194075
GROUP BY cb.customer_basket_id;
```

Information at the product level doesn't make sense at the basket level.  You could create lists of product names, using, say:

```
group_concat(p.products_name) as Products_Name
```

but individual values don't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you will get the resulting sum at the last row of the query.

All other columns will be null.

```
SELECT  cb.customers_id, 
        cb.products_id, 
        cb.customers_basket_quantity, 
        p.products_model, 
        p.products_price, 
        pd.products_name,
        (p.products_price * cb.customers_basket_quantity) AS product_total,
        null as cart_total
    FROM products p 
        INNER JOIN customers_basket cb ON p.products_id = cb.products_id
        INNER JOIN products_description pd ON pd.products_id = p.products_id
    WHERE cb.customers_id = 194075

union all

SELECT null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
        SUM(p.products_price * cb.customers_basket_quantity) AS cart_total
    FROM products p 
        INNER JOIN customers_basket cb ON p.products_id = cb.products_id
    WHERE cb.customers_id = 194075
```

[image: sample data]